# Is there a way to make interactive standalone SVGs in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Current libraries for making "interactive SVGs" in the web-browser are actually using javascript to manipulate a svg object in the page dynamically but don't actually embed the full javascript needed to animate the SVG in the svg tag itself. Libraries like d3.js, protovis, svg.js, etc.

But it's possible to create standalone interactive SVGs, for example Brendan Gregg's flamegraph tool, example:
http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpu-bash-flamegraph.svg

Is there any way to create a standalone, interactive SVG in a webpage? Of course, you could generate the interactive SVG serverside (for example, Brendan uses a Perl library to generate the interactive SVG) and then serve that to the user. But I'd prefer to generate the SVG as part of generating the webpage itself, i.e. in Php or Ruby or, even better, client-side with a Javascript library. In either case, the key feature goal is to be able to right-click-download the custom-made interactive SVG.

Note: The benefit of the d3.js approach is that the animation can be integrated between the SVG and other DOM elements on the page, or have interaction with the SVG trigger dynamic AJAX requests. I'm not expecting the stand-alone SVG to be able to do these things.

Comment: Have you tried `<img src="myInteractive.svg" />` or  `<object data="myInteractive.svg"></object>` ?

Comment: @Dai clarified the question, I'm trying to generate the interactive SVG dynamically. Javascript would be ideal but having it be part of the webpage serving language (PHP/Ruby/etc) would also be acceptable.

Comment: You can still do that by serializing the dynamically-built SVG into a `data:` URI and using the DOM to make that the `src=""` of the `<img />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, You can inline an interactive SVG into the `src=` of an `<embed>` DOM element using a `data:` URI.

Unfortunately, current web browsers don't have right click -> download for `<embed>` elements, only for `<img>` tags. We can't use `<img>` because that tag won't run the javascript code inside the SVG for security reasons.

Luckily, we can hack in our own download link using javascript as follows:

```
 <embed class="mygraph" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8, ... svg code ...>
 <a download class="downloadLink">Download this graph.</a>
 <script>
 document.querySelector(".downloadLink").href = document.querySelector(".mygraph").src;
 </script>
```

If you try to use this technique to make standalone SVGs using popular libraries like d3.js you'll need to change a few things that are browser specific to work inside the SVG context. It took around 4 lines of code change to use d3.v5.js inside a standalone SVG without errors.

You can see an example of it here:
https://github.com/bjmnbraun/d3-standalone

Comment: "it took around 3 lines of code change to use d3..." - why not include that code as a reference?

Comment: @ZachSaucier added an example